# Add '...' After UILabel Word Wrapped Property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel that has max-lines of 2, and a word wrapping property. This is done in storyboard.

I need to add a '...' after the last wrapped word on those labels that end up being word wrapped.

Is this possible? I have tried some solutions from around the internet, but they seem to have not worked. Those include:

- Testing label if it has been truncated, and appending '...' to those that have been.
- Programmatically using attributed text to hijack storyboard.
- Tried using Truncate Tail - Unable to use this because it cuts the word off like so "Highli...".

Comment: @Rikh Correct - It truncates halfway, which is not what the client wants. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. This is a bit sloppy, but it should work

```
 extension UILabel {
        func truncateAndFitText()
        {
            if let string = self.text
            {
                let words = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
                var lastString = ""
                var tempString = ""

                for word in words 
                {
                    (tempString == "") ? tempString.append(word) : tempString.append(" \(word)")
                    let size: CGSize = tempString.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self.font])
                    if (size.width > (self.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(self.numberOfLines)))
                    {
                        lastString.append("...")
                        break
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lastString = tempString
                    }
                }

                self.text = lastString
            }
        }
    }
```

and then use it like

```
myLabel.truncateAndFitText
```